# Find and extract a certain value in a file

Tags: c++, file

Doing a project that requires to load an existing file and I was wondering how to extract a certain value for example:

If file Joe Shmoe contains:

```
Here is your information:
Name:    Joe Shmoe
Address: 123 Street St
Balance: $300
```

How would I be able to extract Joe Shmoe, 123 Street St and 300 into individual variables? (Don't know why some words are blue, they just supposed to be normal)

Comment: What have you tried yourself already?

Comment: what did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I haven't tried because I don't know how to do it, I was hoping you guys could help me out. I'm guessing it has to do something with getline and ignore but I don't really know how either of those work for files.

Comment: They work the same as they work on all other input_streams, like `cin`. That's the beauty of it. Of course assuming you use `std::ifstream`.

Comment: I have to use fstream with ios::in and ios::out because I have to be able to edit the outputs.

Comment: This type of question gets asked multiple times a _day_. Search and you will find many, many such questions. Study their answers and you'll get a very good idea of how to do what you want to do.

Comment: `fstream` with `ios::in` and `ios::out` is an input stream, too.

Answer (score 0):

Small explanation of `std::getline` and `ignore`, `in` is always an input stream.

```cpp
std::string s;
char c = '\n';
std::getline(in, s, c);
```

reads the rest of the current line (so up to `c`). The read part is removed from `in` and everything excluding `c` is put in `s`. If you don't supply a `c`, the default `'\n'` (end of line) will be used.

```cpp
std::streamsize len = 1; 
int c = -1; // You can also take a char and write for example char c = '\n' to ignore to the end of the line.
in.ignore(len, c);
```

will remove up to `len` characters from `in`. It stops before, if it reaches `c` (`-1` says it never stops on this way). The defaults are as above, but normally one will use `len = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` (the maximal value the input parameter can have) and `char c = '\n'`. Then it basically does what `std::getline(in, s)` would do but discards the string (it actually never creates it).

Comment: Don't count on a null character at the end of a file. What n314159 is REALLY doing is counting on the text file not containing any null characters (usually a safe bet) so that it will read until `len` characters or the end of the file is reached.

Comment: Ah, yes. I actually wanted to take the default which is `std::basic_istream<CharT>::traits_type::eof()`, but that would just be confusing and then I mixed up `\0` and EOF and thought `\0` would encode EOF.